# Scraping a website with cURL request not reading the HTML code

Tags: php, web-crawler

Crawling http://www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html?cod=299 is not working.
It's getting redirected to some other location. But why?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html?cod=299';
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
$redirectURL = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
curl_close($curl);
echo $html;
?>
```

I'm unable to understand why this happening.

Comment: probably being rejected deliberately if they do not want to allow bulk download. the site does not allow google translation, even! try that to see the kind of error your curl client might be hitting.

Comment: Curl can't follow Javascript redirect or META redirect

Comment: Can you crawl the site with a browser with JavaScript turned off? Maybe the site needs JS to work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `htmlspecialchars()` to get the source code of the response

```
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

It's likely that there is a javascript or meta redirect in there somewhere. My JS is so poor i can't really help you with that.

If you can find that, you can build a regular expression to find the URL and then fetch it's contents.